# Can't force LINQ evaluation

Tags: linq, automapper

I'm trying to get a record and store it for later use if an error occurs on the page.

This code is used on Create/Edit. So I'm getting values from a View Model and mapping to the db entity:

```
Dim objExistingSupplier As SUPPLIER = db.SUPPLIER.Single(Function(e) e.SUPPLIER_ID = Supplier.SUPPLIER_ID)
objPermStaffAction = objExistingSupplier
objSupplier = Mapper.Map(Of SupplierViewModel, SUPPLIER)(Supplier, objExistingSupplier)
```

From what I understand, the .Single should force evaluation. However, after the mapping occurs properties are lost/changed in the objPermStaffAction object. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the whole function:

```
    Private Function SaveSupplier(Supplier As SupplierViewModel) As ActionResult
        Dim objSupplier, objPermStaffAction As SUPPLIER
        If Supplier.SUPPLIER_ID = 0 Then
            objSupplier = Mapper.Map(Of SupplierViewModel, SUPPLIER)(Supplier)
        Else
            Dim objExistingSupplier As SUPPLIER = db.SUPPLIER.Single(Function(e) e.SUPPLIER_ID = Supplier.SUPPLIER_ID)
            objPermStaffAction = objExistingSupplier
            objSupplier = Mapper.Map(Of SupplierViewModel, SUPPLIER)(Supplier, objExistingSupplier)
        End If

        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            If Supplier.SUPPLIER_ID = 0 Then
                objSupplier.CREATED_BY = Session("AppUserID")
                db.SUPPLIER.Add(objSupplier)
            Else
                objSupplier.UPDATED_BY = Session("AppUserID")
                UpdateModel(objSupplier)
            End If

            Try
                db.SaveChanges()
                Return RedirectToAction("Index")
            Catch ex As Exception
                If InStr(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message, "PRSNL.SUPPLIER_UK") > 0 Then
                    ModelState.AddModelError("SUPPLIER_CODE", "Supplier Code already exists. Please choose another.")
                End If
            End Try

        End If

        'This will run if an error occured
        If Supplier.SUPPLIER_ID > 0 Then
            Supplier = Mapper.Map(Of SupplierViewModel)(objPermStaffAction)
        End If
        ViewBag.YNList = Common.GetYNList
        Return View(Supplier)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

SupplierViewModel is reference type. So objPermStaffAction refer to the same object which is getting updated after mapping.

Why do you need original (not mapped) object?

Comment: Sorry, I can see why you'd make that assumption. I edited the text to describe the scenario a bit better. I'm also looking for an answer that describes why objPermStaffAction on line 2 doesn't retain it's property values after the mapping on line 3.

Comment: On the Edit form I display read-only audit info (created_by, create_dt, updated_by, update_dt). If a validation error occurs these values go away when the form reloads. I'll post the whole function.

Comment: Is there a way to "disconnect" objPermStaffAction so that the values won't change after the mapping?

Comment: Shallow copy should be enough -> objPermStaffAction = objExistingSupplier.Clone()

Comment: Good thought, but it looks like I'd have to add the Clone method to the db entity that's created by Entity Framework. That'll get overwritten every time I have to update it and I've got multiple places where I need to implement this.

Am I just going about this all wrong? How do you code this so that a validation error doesn't leave any fields blank? Do you know of any examples of what I'm trying to do?